# How to identify the font family name from latex font catalogue

Tags: fonts

I want to change the font in my different paragraphs.

for that I am using this commands,

`\fontfamily{font-family-name}\selectfont`

in some cases I am defining an environment for the font and  I am using.

### Question:

Eventhough I can find the good fonts installed in my texlive from the latex catalogue expecially [hand writing fonts](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/calligraphicalfonts.html)

I couldnot find the font family name.. to use that font.

How to do that.??

Comment: you may visit the `.sty` file of the package loading that font to find out the family name, or try out the method of the answer linked to in next comment. The former method may have twists though as sometimes the `.sty` file constructs the internal font name from options it receives. Note also that bypassing the package might lead to problems if the package provides some scaling options for example and sets some macros to some default value. You would then have to replicate that to some extent.